SQL query with 2 columns inserted into new table?
I have a SQL query that returns two columns (always one row):
SELECT 
    SUM(firstmeasure) AS col1, COUNT(*) AS col2
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         date1, date2,
         CASE 
             WHEN DATEDIFF(date1, date2) < 20 
                 THEN 1 
                 ELSE 0 
         END firstmeasure
     FROM 
         table1) x
WHERE 
    date1 >= '01/01/2024'




col1
col2




100
180



I would like to INSERT both of these values into another table (essentially it is recording the point-in-time result of the query)
INSERT INTO table2 (col1, col2)

How do I do this without executing the query twice? For example I am able to assign the result of the query to 1 variable and insert that, but only if the query is reduced to only producing 1 column.

I regular insert can use a select... so just add the insert before your select. (The documentation is very good with SQL Server syntax).

>= '20240101' or >= DATEFROMPARTS(2024,1,1). This regional format of m/d/y (or is it d/m/y?) is trouble waiting to happen.

INSERT INTO table2(col1, col2)
SELECT SUM(firstmeasure) AS col1, COUNT(*) AS col2
FROM (
    SELECT date1, date2
        , CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(date1,date2) < 20 THEN 1 ELSE ) END 'firstmeasure'
    FROM table1
) x
WHERE date1 >= '01/01/2024'


Why use a different name for table2???

@testing-for-ya The OP has table2 the answer had t2

@MatBailie Yeah, I saw the new version before I read your comment. Still, it's all pseudo-code, eh? The OP doesn't have table1 or table2 or t2 in their system, and the actual explicit names aren't important.

CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(date1,date2) < 20 THEN 1 ELSE ) END shouldn't compile, but same mistake was in OPs code

IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT    1 
              FROM      tablename WITH(NOLOCK)
              WHERE     col1 = 'D1')
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO tablename 
    (
        col1                    ,
        col2
    )
    VALUES
    (  
       'D1'    ,
       'Data1'  
    )
END
GO

